# Preventing a fixed element from moving up past certain height on resize

Tags: jquery, css, resize, element, fixed

I have a few icons positioned to the bottom and right of the page. When resizing the window I'd like the icons to dissappear, otherwise they conflict with the content above. I've managed to fix the problem when resizing left to right using min-width, but can't seem to find the solution using min-height.

Both JQuery and CSS welcomed.
The icons are given a class(.icon) and nested within a section(#footer).
Here is what I have;

CSS

```
#footer .icons{
position: fixed;
bottom:10px;
left:0;
width:98%;
min-width:1350px;
```

}

```
.icons{
display:inline-block;
text-align:right;
    z-index:-9999;
float:right;
right:10px;
padding:2px;
bottom:10px;
```

}

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should check media queries to show / hide elements according to the window dimensions.  Here is the Mozilla documentation: [@media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Comment: Have you considered using media queries? [Media Queries on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use a bit of JQuery, it's quite simple!

```
.unfixed_icons {
    position: relative
    top: [whatever you want]
    left: [whatever you want]
}
```

You keep the same html as you have above, don't add the class `unfixed_icons` to anything.

```
if $(document).height() > $(window).height()
    $('.icons').addClass 'unfixed_icons'
else
    $('.icons').removeClass 'unfixed_icons'
```

Sorry that's in coffeescript, but I think you'll understand. The first line is most important – you check to see if the document is as tall as the window's viewport. If it is, you make the icons positioned relatively (so they will go away), otherwise they'll stay fixed.

This will work fine for whenever someone reloads the page, but if you want it to reset when someone resizes the window too you'll need something like this:

```
(window).resize ->
    clearTimeout(resizeTimer)
    resizeTimer = setTimeout(position_function, 100)
```

Where the `position_function` would equal the jquery/coffeescript above. In essence, you're re-checking the footer ever .1 seconds as they're reloading the page, to make sure it's positioned correctly.

Good luck!